# How to select two rows from one table?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use `mysql_query` to select two rows from one table with the usage of *pid* twice.

Like this:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$user1' AND pid='$user2' order by id desc limit 50") ?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have to use `OR` instead of `AND` in where clause.

Comment: Thank You  now everything is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$user1' OR pid='$user2' order by id desc limit 50
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeap its working , but now i have one more problem -.-'
I selected that my code select * from persons where user1='$_SESSION[user]' AND friends='yes' , and another code needs to echo from posts (code above) and when i go to my database to table persons and select that user1 and user 2 are friends , and user1 and user 3 are friends , it only echo from my account and from user2, but user3 is not working :( , does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: can't understand what you want to do? :(
be specific and show us what did you tried so far.?

Comment: `$res5=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE user1='$_SESSION[user]' AND friends='yes'");
 $row5=mysql_fetch_array($res5);
$user2=$row5['user2'];`


`<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$_SESSION[user]' OR pid='$user2' order by id desc limit 5000") ?>
<?php while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>`

Two querys , so last query needs to output users posts , now it only display posts from one friend , now all of them

Like user1 and user2 are friends , and user1 and user3 are friends , it only displays posts from first data on database. Like from friend 2

Comment: If i change that my first friend is user3 than it will show posts from me and user3 , but second data in database is that user1(me) and user2 are friends , but only displays from user3 -.-

Comment: `<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid='$_SESSION[user]' OR pid='$user2' order by id desc limit 5000") ?> <?php while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>` with this code it will display posts from last person inserted as friends , and if i delete `ORDER BY id desc limit 5000` it will display posts from first person marked as friend , but i want to display posts from every friend...